# AJAX Click Counter Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, click, counter

I need a simple click counter for links in my wordpress posts. I used google a lot but couldnt find a working one. I want to count clicks from a specific class and store it in post_meta or as a custom field to display the count later.

here is some code i found but i cant get it to work..nothting happens when i click the link.

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("a[link-out]").click(function() {
        var linkout = $(this).attr("link-out");
        var data = {
            action: 'my_action',
            postid: linkout
        };
        $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, data);
    });

});
```

php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/countclicks.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
// declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_id = $_POST['postid'];
    $post_id = mysql_real_escape_string($post_id);
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value+1 WHERE post_id = '$post_id' AND meta_key = 'clicks_out'");
}
```

here is another one i found here on stackoverflow, but also doenst work
[coding ajax click counter on wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320710/coding-ajax-click-counter-on-wordpress)

Comment: Any output in the console?

Comment: do you mean for example in chrome search elements console? if so then no there is nothing